# Submit PHP form with 6000 rows data

Tags: php

Actually I have a form which is taking approx 6000 data and when i submit to insert these 6000 rows for insert into mySq-DB then its taking much time and most of time its get hanged.

Note : Rows Are Created By Excel Upload And After Upload Of Excel Its Created Rows(6000) On PHP Script (view) Page. And after that we click on submit button to store these rows data into my mysql-DB.

My PHP/HTML Page Contains:

```
prod_id prod_name prod_sku  Created_on  Created_by  Modified_on Modified_by
  1     Samsung   XYZ       2015-07-17    1         2015-08-18    1
  2     Micromax  ABC       2015-07-17    1         2015-08-18    1
  3     HTC Des   PQR       2015-07-17    4         2015-08-18    4
  4     HTC FLY   MVC       2015-07-17    44        2015-08-18    44
  5     LG G2     UVW       2015-07-17    66        2015-08-18    66
  6     LG G4     XYZ       2015-07-17    22        2015-08-18    22
  7     Sony      LMN       2015-07-17    44        2015-08-18    44
  8     Dell      DEF       2015-07-17    1         2015-08-18    1
```

Image for Excel [image]

Comment: Kindly share If any one have any solution for this problem.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Why does it need to be displayed on the page? for editing/review? Haven't user already done it in Excel? Strange workflow...

Comment: actually i have a excel sheets which contains products details and its containing approx 6000 rows which i have to insert into my mysql-db but its get hanged and most of data get failed to insert.

Comment: Submitting 6000 rows of data to a DB is not a good use of http. It's not the right tool for the job. Why are you trying to do this? Maybe somebody can suggest a better way of doing what you want.

Comment: For adding More Info into Excel Fields Such as current price and moreover . Therefor its need to show excel list on htm/php view page for editing after that we submit them.

Comment: @octopus- Kindly share if there is any better way for this.

Comment: try to use set_time_limit(0)

Comment: @DheerajNayak you just need to update the item you've modified.You could do that using AJAX with a background php file to handler it.

Comment: You would need to add more details. Do you transfer the form via post or get. How do you insert the data into the database, .... else its just guessing what you are doing aka how you try to accomplish things and are failliing.

Comment: I guess the best solution is load directly this to database and set the flag (a database filed) - finalized = 0. List these data in paginated form - may be 10 items per page - and give a provision to edit each rows.

Comment: Thanks@TismonVarghese and Thomas

Answer (score 0):

For loading huge amounts of data into MySQL, `LOAD DATA INFILE` is by far the fastest option.

[Approx- 40,000 Rows]

First, convert your Excel file into a CSV.

These steps can be used to emulate this functionality:

1. Create a new temporary table.

   ```
   CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temporary_table LIKE target_table;
   ```
2. Optionally, drop all indices from the temporary table to speed things up.

   ```
   SHOW INDEX FROM temporary_table;
   DROP INDEX `PRIMARY` ON temporary_table;
   DROP INDEX `some_other_index` ON temporary_table;
   ```
3. Load the CSV into the temporary table

   ```
   LOAD DATA INFILE 'your_file.csv'
   INTO TABLE temporary_table
   FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
   (field1, field2);
   ```
4. Copy the data using `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`

   ```
   SHOW COLUMNS FROM target_table;
   INSERT INTO target_table
   SELECT * FROM temporary_table
   ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE field1 = VALUES(field1), field2 = VALUES(field2);
   ```
5. Remove the temporary table

   ```
   DROP TEMPORARY TABLE temporary_table;
   ```

Using `SHOW INDEX FROM` and `SHOW COLUMNS FROM` this process can be automated for any given table.